# how to configure all cmmon file in jest?

Tags: jestjs, babel-jest

how to load all common file in jest.config

how to load all common file and 3td party library's like jquery

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "jest": {
    setupFiles:[../src/assert]
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect?

Comment: in every test file importing every librarys like global.$ = require('jquery');
global.moment = require('moment.js'); i dont want import common librarys in each file.what is the best  practices jest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [setupFiles](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfiles-array) in `jest.config.js`. Assign the `jquery` and `moment` to node.js `global` object. Then, you can get the them in each test cases using `global.$` and `global.moment`.

E.g.

`setup.js`:

```js
const jquery = function () {
  return "I'm fake jquery";
};
const moment = function () {
  return "I'm fake moment";
};

global.$ = jquery;
global.moment = moment;
```

`jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts',
  testEnvironment: 'enzyme',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    'jest-enzyme',
    './jest.setup.js',
  ],
  setupFiles: [
    '/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/react-apollo-graphql-starter-kit/stackoverflow/61727628/setup.js',
  ],
  testMatch: ['**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)'],
  verbose: true,
};
```

`a.test.js`:

```js
describe('61727628', () => {
  describe('a', () => {
    it('should pass', () => {
      console.log('global.$:', global.$);
      console.log('global.moment:', global.moment);
      expect(1 + 1).toBe(2);
    });
  });
});
```

`b.test.js`:

```js
describe('61727628', () => {
  describe('b', () => {
    it('should pass', () => {
      console.log('global.$:', global.$);
      console.log('global.moment:', global.moment);
      expect(1 + 1).toBe(2);
    });
  });
});
```

unit test results:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/61727628/a.test.js
  61727628
    a
      ✓ should pass (28ms)

  console.log
    global.$: function () {
        return "I'm fake jquery";
    }

      at Object.<anonymous> (stackoverflow/61727628/b.test.js:4:15)

  console.log
    global.$: function () {
        return "I'm fake jquery";
    }

      at Object.<anonymous> (stackoverflow/61727628/a.test.js:4:15)

  console.log
    global.moment: function () {
        return "I'm fake moment";
    }

      at Object.<anonymous> (stackoverflow/61727628/a.test.js:5:15)

  console.log
    global.moment: function () {
        return "I'm fake moment";
    }

      at Object.<anonymous> (stackoverflow/61727628/b.test.js:5:15)

 PASS  stackoverflow/61727628/b.test.js
  61727628
    b
      ✓ should pass (28ms)

Test Suites: 2 passed, 2 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        6.026s, estimated 16s
```

Comment: how to mock below method this.apiCall('/getuser',{id:1}  function (err, response) {
                if (!err && response) {
                    var data = JSON.parse(response.toString().replace(/'/g, '"'));
                    if ( data.success) {
                      let user= data.value;
       this.name=User.name;
       this.Id=user.id;
       this.loc=user.loc;
                    }
                    
                }
        
            });

Comment: @SamJay Please ask a new question. This is a different question with this post

Comment: could you please look at once  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61815681/how-to-mock-api-and-inside-foreach-or-map-loop-in-jest